# How to calculate height and width of the clicked image via camera in android

Tags: android, image-processing, camera

I use camera to click image(object) in the app, after clicking the photo, I want to know the height and width of the object.
Please guide me.

Comment: There's no code pasted, so it's not clear what you're asking. But if you want to see the width and height of an image you took, why not just open it in a photo viewer and click 'details'?

Comment: thanks for the reply.. this is not the case. let suppose I clicked the image and in that image there is GLASS, so I want to calculate the height and width of that GLASS in the app only.

Comment: Your question is subject of PhD studies in the field of Computer Vision. So it's not a good question for StackOverflow and very soon other people should vote to close and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) first in `onActivityResult` method then get height and width of bitmap

`java.io.File file = new java.io.File(
                            this.application.getDirectory(),
                            this.application.getFileName());
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        Bitmap bitmapPhoto =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputPath);
height = bitmapPhoto.getHeight();
width = bitmapPhoto.getWidth()
}`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I dont want to calculate the height and width of the full image, I want to calculate the height and width of any object inside the image. let suppose I clicked the image and in that image there is GLASS, so I want to calculate the height and width of that GLASS in the app only.

Answer (score 0):

I got what you need,
Firstly you have to integrate **Opencv** Library into your application, Then use **Object detection** in OpenCv, You have to click on the object you need to measure(height,width);

By using below formula you can get all you need.

```
realWorldHeight = rect.size().height / imageMat.size().height * realWorldDistanceToObject * Math.cos( realWorldAngleOfObjectHeight / 2);
```